# I want to add a newline between elements in my list (python)

Tags: python

```
def writeConfusionMatrix(self, outFile):
    print("Write a confusion matrix to outFile; elements in the matrix can be frequencies (you don't need to normalize)")

    output = []

    file = open(outFile, 'w+')

    matrix = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))

    for s in range(len(self.goldenTags)):
        for w in range(len(self.goldenTags[s])):
            matrix[self.goldenTags[s][w].tag][self.myTags[s][w].tag] += 1

    row_ids = sorted(matrix.keys())
    col_ids = sorted(set(k for v in matrix.values() for k in v.keys()))

    output.append(col_ids)

    for r in row_ids:
        output.append([r] + [matrix[r].get(c, 0) for c in col_ids])
    #matKeys = matrix.keys()
    #df = DataFrame(matrix).T.fillna(0)
    #output = '\n'.join(output)
    print(output)
    file.write(str(output))
```

This function creates a confusion matrix and writes it into a new file.

It looks like

[current matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xP5N.png)

It's nested list with no spaces, but I want to make it look like:

[new matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/95x21.png)

by adding new lines in between the elements.

I've tried something like adding

```
output = '\n'.join(output)
```

before

```
file.write(str(output))
```

but gave me a

```
sequence item 0: expected str instance, list found
```

error.

Any idea?

Comment: `file.write('\n'.join(str(item) for item in lst))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try writing this to your file:

```
output = '\n'.join([','.join(map(str,item)) for item in output])
```

You were joining lists with `'\n'.join()` and you need to convert those to string as well.

Comment: Am i supposed put this right before file.write? It gives me an error: sequence item 1: expected str instance, int found

Answer (score 2):

Simply print your string line by line:

```
for line in output:
    print line # or file.write(line)
```

Or create a new string that uses the new line separator and then write it:

```
output = '\n'.join(str(line) for line in output)
print line # or file.write(line)
```